# Show a minimizer of distance to a dot on image of a diffeomorphiism

Tags: analysis

Let $f: D \rightarrow f\left(D\right)$ a diffeomorphism, $D = \left \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: \left |x \right |^{2} < R^{2}\right \}$ and $\left |f\left(x\right) - f\left(y\right) \right| > \left | x - y \right |, \forall x, y \in D$. I want to show that $B = \left \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: \left | f\left(x\right) - f\left(0\right)\right |^{2} < R^{2}\right \} \subset f\left(D\right)$. My attempts:

$\cdot$ If $f\left(D\right) = \mathbb{R}^{2}$ it's trivial;

$\cdot$ Suppose that $f\left(D\right) \neq \mathbb{R}^{2}$, if $\exists \theta \in f\left(D\right)^{c}$ (here is my doubt) such that $\theta$ minimize distance between $f\left(D\right)^{c}$ and $f\left(0\right)$, then I can choose a sequence in $D$ such that $f\left(x_{n}\right) \rightarrow \theta$, so $\left |x_{n}\right | \rightarrow R$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$, if it's not true, we have a obviously contradiction, then $\left | f\left(x_{n}\right) - f\left(0\right)\right | > \left |x_{n}\right| \Rightarrow \left | \theta - f\left(0\right) \right | \geq R \Rightarrow \theta \in B^{c}$ and any another point will be in $B^{c}$ because $\theta$ minize distance, then $f\left(D\right)^{c} \subset B^{c}$.

So, if exists that $\theta$ I know how solve this, but I don't see how can I show this existence.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is a diffeomorphism, $E=f(D)$ is open. If it's not all of $\mathbb R^2$ there is a ball $B(f(0),r)$ which contains some point of $E^c$. Then $\overline B(f(0),r)\cap E^c$ is nonempty, closed and bounded, therefore compact. Now you conclude because there's always a point of minimum distance from a compact set ( any limit point of any minimizing sequence works)

Comment: Ok, I understand this, but with this could I to take some sequence how I took ?

Comment: Yes. In fact any sequence $(y_n)\subset f(D)$ converging to $\theta$ has the property that $x_n=f^{-1}(y_n)$ goes to the boundary of $D$. Otherwise you would get a limit point of $x_n$ inside $B(0,R')$ with $R'<R$, and by continuity of $f$ $\theta$ should be inside $f(D)$, contradiction.

Comment: Just another thing that I didn't get it. Why I can take this $\left(y_{n}\right)$ converging to $\theta$?

Comment: Because otherwise there would be a ball around $\theta$ entirely contained in the complement of $f(D)$, and therefore $\theta$ could not be a point of minimum distance from $f(0)$